# How can i get the Passing/Failing status of a Github Action Workflow?

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions, building-github-actions

I have been looking at the GitHub REST API and i have been trying to find out where I can find the endpoint to get the status of a workflow in my actions. The only way i can tell if it is passing or failing is by downloading the badge.svg.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [workflow run api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#list-workflow-runs) :

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/[owner]/[repo]/actions/workflows/[workflowID]/runs
```

`[workflowID]` can also be the filename, in the following example `ci.yml` :

https://api.github.com/repos/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping/actions/workflows/ci.yml/runs

Then you can get the first run using `curl` and `jq` :

```sh
curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping/actions/workflows/ci.yml/runs" | \
    jq -r '.workflow_runs[0].status'
```

output:

```
completed
```